# Is there a fatest way to go check each line of a table in Capybara?

Tags: automated-tests, capybara

I'm using capybara to go throught a table that has the name of a country in a column and a dropdown with names in another.

The code is like this:

```
 within('tbody') do
  all('tr').each do |line|
    unless line.has_css?('United Kingdom')
      if line.has_css?('span', text: 'Austria')
        find('input[id*="_name-selectized"]').click
        find('div[data-selectable]', text: austria_person.name).click
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But this is too slow, I want to know if there is a fastest way to see each line and select a dropdown option according to the country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capybara provides automatic waiting/retrying behavior on most of its methods (all and first don't by default) due to the asynchronous nature of most web apps.  This is great for most cases where you're looking for exactly what you need to be on the page, however in a case like yours where you're making decisions on what to do based on what is or isn't on the page it can lead to delays.

For example, in your code when you call `line.has_css?('United Kingdom')` Capybara is waiting up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time for the text to appear.  If you know the row is loaded and isn't going to be dynamically changing then that waiting is just wasted time.  Luckily you can disable the waiting time by passing `wait: false` (or 0).

Therefore

```
within('tbody') do
  all('tr').each do |line|
    unless line.has_css?('United Kingdom', wait: false)
      if line.has_css?('span', text: 'Austria', wait: false)
        find('input[id*="_name-selectized"]').click
        find('div[data-selectable]', text: austria_person.name).click
      end
    end
  end
end
```

will probably be significantly faster for you.  A second optimization could be if the items you need to click on are actually in the row then scope those to reduce the amount of elements that have to be searched.

```
within('tbody') do
  all('tr').each do |line|
    within(line) do        
      unless page.has_css?('United Kingdom', wait: false)
        if page.has_css?('span', text: 'Austria', wait: false)
          find('input[id*="_name-selectized"]').click
          find('div[data-selectable]', text: austria_person.name).click
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If there are a lot of spans per line you could also speed up the `line.has_css?('span', text: 'Austria', wait: false)` by switching to an XPath that checks the text in the XPath expression (rather than using the `text` option) since it would mean the browser would find the correct span rather than returning every span to Capybara which then has to check the text.